# How do I use PySpark to Parse Large Mailbox Files

Tags: python, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say that I have a **Unix mailbox file** (*.mbox) so large that I cannot possibly hope to fit it into memory all at once, and I don't want to deal with breaking it up, task scheduling and cancellation, fault recovery, etc.

I decide it might be a good idea to use **Apache Spark** for this task, and to write a Python program to make it easily repeatable.

I know that the best solution is to somehow use one of the many great MBOX file parsers available to the Python community, **but how to I do I submit that work to a Spark cluster?**

The following is invalid code, but I'm hoping it can help relay my end goal.

```
import email
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions
import re 

# a python function that separates the mbox files into separate 
# emails using a regex to read the first line of each email
def transformData(x):
    indices = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('From [0-9]+@xxx', x)]
    return [x[i:j] for i, j in zip(indices, indices[1:]+[None])]

spark = SparkSession.builder
             .master("spark://localhost:7077")
             .appName("EmailParser")
             .getOrCreate()

inbox = spark.sparkContext.textFile(    
             "file:///C:/Users/baugh/Desktop/Takeout/Mail/Inbox.mbox")

rddOfEmailsOrSomething = lines.map(lambda x: transformData(x)).collect()

# this should be a list of email objects with good properties
# like 'to', 'from' and 'subject', etc.
listOfEmails = list()

for _email in rddOfEmailsOrSomething:
     emailToAdd = email.message_from_string(_email)
     listOfEmails.append(emailToAdd)

print(listOfEmails[0].from)
# returns "example@example.com"
```

Typically, when I cannot find any resources online that help me figure it out, it means that I'm trying to solve the problem the wrong way and need to think about it differently. Is that the case here? I am very new to Apache Spark and PySpark, but I know some Python.

Any help, resources, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're never using the spark DataFrame you're creating. I would look up UDF's and try to make your transformData function a UDF so that it can execute over the rows in your spark DataFrame. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf

Comment: @DavidSchuler Thank you, will do immediately. I will update the question or provide an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up decided it's a good time to learn Scala. What I ended up doing was just processing the file in a `foreach` loop like normal, but created a Queue that each parsed email would get added to, and from there it would get saved to the DB, this way I don't block the thread waiting on the DB.